# Difficulty writing simple program demonstrating local variables and global statement

Tags: python

I just started programming and I chose python as my first language. I was reading about local variables and the global statement in functions and I decided to write a simple program to get some practice. The goal of the program is to start off with x=50, then create a function with one parameter called x, change local x to 2 and then write another function without parameters changing global x to 3. So when I did it and called the functions separately, like this

```
x = 50

def func(x):
    print 'x is', x
    x = 2
    print 'Changed local x to', x

func(x)
print 'x is still', x


def func():
    global x

    print 'x is', x
    x = 3
    print 'Changed global x to', x

func()
print 'Value of x is', x
```

everything worked well. But when I call one after the other, like this

```
x=50


def func(x):
    print 'x is', x
    x = 2
    print 'Changed local x to', x



def func():
    global x

    print 'x is', x
    x = 3
    print 'Changed global x to', x

func(x)
print 'x is still', x

func()
print "Value of x is", x
```

it   doesn't work. Here is the terminal

```
pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~$ cd /home/pedro/Desktop/python
pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/python$ python testperfect.py
x is 50
Changed local x to 2
x is still 50
x is 50
Changed global x to 3
Value of x is 3
pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/python$ python test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    func(x)
TypeError: func() takes no arguments (1 given)
pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/python$
```

. What did I do wrong? I use ubuntu as OS, gedit as text editor and the terminal pre installed in ubuntu. Testperct.py is the file that works and test2.py is the one that doesn't.

Comment: HINT: What do you think happens when you define two functions with the same name?

Comment: You defined `func()` twice, so the last definition `func()` --with no arguments-- stays. Thus, when you call `func(x)`, the argument `x` is unexpected, yielding a `TypeError`. Define the second `func()` as `func2()` and then use `func(x)` and `func2()` (where the second call has no arguments).

Answer (score 3):

Python [doesn't support function overloading](http://web.archive.org/web/20090624083829/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-May/206149.html).
So, as @Noble Mushtak and @bsoist have noticed - previously defined function would be overwritten by later defined.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading) for details.

Comment: @bsoist noticed it too :)