# Two functions of the same name in Python

Tags: python

I have a *requirement* that I have to write two functions with the same name in Python. How should I do it?

```
class QueueCards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def Add(self, other):
        self.cards.insert(0, other)

    def Add(self, listCards, numCards):
        for i in numCards:
            card = listCards.GetCard(i)
            self.Add(card)
```

`Count()` is the size of the queue.

Comment: The real question is, _why_ would you do it?

Comment: I'm studying computer science and I've been asked to do it unfortunately

Comment: It can be done, its just not pretty and youll probably have to use a package designed to do this. Check out my answer below, it has a nice solution to your question.

Comment: @rotemhas, do they both have to be methods?

Comment: `numCards` is not used in your function. Cannot you simply do `def add_cards(cards): for card in cards: self.add(card)`?

Comment: To add to Rogalski's comment, there's no reason why the size of the `QueueCards` object (given by `self.Count`) should be related to the size of `listCards`.

Comment: Are you certain the requirement is "write two functions with the same name"? Or, is the requirement "write a function that can be called two different ways"?

Comment: Aw the numCards is a mistake. I changed it, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it. At least, not in the same namespace (i.e.: same module, or same class). It seems you are trying to do something you've learned in one language and are trying to apply it to Python.

Instead, you can have `Add` take a variable number of arguments, so you can do different things depending on what was passed in.

```
def Add(self, *args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        item = args[0]
        self.cards.insert(0, item)

    elif len(args) == 2):
        listCards, numCards = args
        for i in numCards:
            card = listCards.GetCard(i)
            self.cards.insert(0, card)
```

Personally I think it is better to have two functions because it avoids ambiguity and aids readability. For example, `AddCard` and `AddMultipleCards`.

Or, perhaps even better, a single function that you use for any number of cards. For example, you can define `Add` to take a list of cards, and you add them all:

```
def Add(self, *args):
    for card in args:
        self.cards.insert(0, card)
```

Then, call it with either a single card:

```
self.Add(listCards.GetCard(0))
```

... or, a list of cards:

```
list_of_cards = [listCards.GetCard(i) for i in range(len(listCards))]
self.Add(*list_of_cards)
```

---

You appear to be asked to do *function overloading*, which is simply not something that Python supports. For more information about function overloading in Python, see this question: *[Python function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading)*

Comment: I think the OP has to do it so they have no choice

Comment: Perhaps see also https://peps.python.org/pep-0443/

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.7, for some reason, you can do this:

```
def xyz():
    print "R"
def xyz():
    print "T"
xyz()
```

If you were to run this, the result would be "T" so the second (or last) version of the function would be called.

I found this out by accident and it took me ages to find out why my program wasn't working!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact it is a *requirement* you have to fulfill,  if you can use a function you can use the function with the same name in the method i.e:

```
def Add(cards, item):
    cards.insert(0, item)

class QueueCards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
    def Add(self, listCards, numCards):
        for i in [1, 2, 3]:
            Add(self.cards, 4)



q = QueueCards()

q.Add(q.cards, 4)
print(q.cards)

[4, 4, 4]
```

Or you can also pass the instance and access the list through the instance:

```
def Add(inst, item):
    inst.cards.insert(0, item)

class QueueCards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def Add(self, listCards, numCards):
        for i in [1, 2, 3]:
           Add(self, numCards)


q = QueueCards()

q.Add(q.cards, 4)
print(q.cards)
```

Which would give you the same output. I could not follow the logic of your methods but the idea will be the same whatever you methods actually do.