# Calling a function from from a function within a class

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I'm fairly new to object oriented programming and have a question on the following.

```
class TestClass():
    def test(arg1,arg2):
        global message
        print(arg1,arg2)
        message=str(arg1)+' '+str(arg2)
        print message

    def test0( self, twoword ):       
        global word1,word2
        word1=twoword.split('-')[0]
        word2=twoword.split('-')[1]
        print(word1,word2)
        TestClass.test(word1,word2)
```

The functionality of the program is redundant and can be simplified but I wish to call the test() from test(). How would one go about this? 
Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you forgot the `self` argument to `test()`. Also, there's no reason to use `global`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `test` a static method (method that can be called without the class instance). You can do it with [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator.

```
class TestClass():
    @staticmethod  # <---
    def test(arg1, arg2):
        global message
        print(arg1,arg2)
        message=str(arg1)+' '+str(arg2)
        print message

    def test0(self, twoword):
        global word1,word2
        word1=twoword.split('-')[0]
        word2=twoword.split('-')[1]
        print(word1,word2)
        TestClass.test(word1,word2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for function overloading 
[Python function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading)

If you just want to make this code work then add a @staticmethod above test.

```
class TestClass():
   @staticmethod
   def test(arg1,arg2):
       global message
       print(arg1,arg2)
       message=str(arg1)+' '+str(arg2)
       print message

   def test0( self, twoword ):
       word1=twoword.split('-')[0]
       word2=twoword.split('-')[0]
       global word1,word2
       print(word1,word2)
       TestClass.test(word1,word2)
```