# Python pattern for defaulting to a 'grandparent' class's implementation

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class Thing(object):
  def sound(self):
    return '' #Silent

class Animal(Thing):
  def sound(self):
    return 'Roar!'

class MuteAnimal(Animal):
   def sound(self):
    return '' #Silent
```

Is there a pattern in python for `MuteAnimal`'s sound to refer to its grandparent class `Thing`'s implementation? (eg `super(MuteAnimal,self).super(Animal.self).sound()` ?) Or is Mixin a better use case here?

Comment: If a class needs direct access to overridden grandparent methods, you have a design problem.

Comment: How would you redesign this ?

Comment: Why does `Thing` automatically sound silent?

Comment: It's hard to say how to redesign a toy example like this, because initial questions like "why is there even a MuteAnimal class at all" and "why do Animals sound like "Roar!" by default" and "why is muteness modeled by a subclass" don't have much of an answer.

Comment: In this way calling a `MuteAnimal_obj.sound()` would return `' '`, so I suppose you could create another method, for example  `def sound1(self): return Thing.sound(self)` that when called would also return also `' '`

Answer (score 0):

As said by [Alexander Rossa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4413406/alexander-rossa) in 
[Python inheritance - how to call grandparent method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016737/python-inheritance-how-to-call-grandparent-method) :

> There are two ways to go around this:
>
> Either you can use explicitly A.foo(self) method as the others have
>   suggested - use this when you want to call the method of the A class
>   with disregard as to whether A is B's parent class or not:
>
> ```
> class C(B):   def foo(self):
>     tmp = A.foo(self) # call A's foo and store the result to tmp
>
> return "C"+tmp
> ```
>
> Or, if you want to use the .foo() method of B's parent class regardless whether the parent class is A or not, then
>   use:
>
> ```
> class C(B):   def foo(self):
>     tmp = super(B, self).foo() # call B's father's foo and store the result to tmp
>     return "C"+tmp
> ```

Comment: Also can overload a method in parent, which calls his parent, then call this method from grandchild. For overloading a function in python, which is not supported directly, take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading

Answer (score -1):

Is it sensible to do this?

In `MuteAnimal.sound`, call `super(Animal, self).sound()`

because Animal is in fact, gradparent class of MuteAnimal...