# Multipledispatch in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain why it doesn't work? I would like to have the same second argument for each function.

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(str, ss=list)
def Func(s, ss=[]):
    return s

@dispatch(list, ss=list)
def Func(l, ss=[]):
    return Func(l[0], ss)

Func(["string"])
```

The error is: `Could not find signature for Func: <str, list>`

Comment: Presumably you're using https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/?

Comment: yes I'm using this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use keyword arguments in `@dispatch`, you must use keyword arguments when calling the function as it already used keyword `ss` as signature to be discoverable.

```
@dispatch(str, ss=list)
def Func(s, ss=[]):
    return s


@dispatch(list, ss=list)
def Func(l, ss=[]):
    return Func(l[0], ss=ss)

Func(["string"])  # output: string
Func("string", [])  # calling this will raise error
Func("string", ss=[])  # output: string
```

Comment: this throws an error...  the same one the OP mentions.

Comment: Please retry. I tested and it worked fine on python 3.7.3.

Comment: So your suggestion is that he add unnecessary keyword arguments which the documentation specifically states it doesn't support.  All so in the end the keyword arguments are useless anyway because the OP is forced to include them in the function signature

Comment: The dispatch does support keyword arguments. It's required if you want to use default parameters (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132640/how-to-use-default-parameter-with-multipledispatch). I'm trying to help OP accomplish what he/she asked, because we maybe do not know the meaning of the keyword argument with default value without context.

Comment: I am still getting an error with all of the function calls you listed

Comment: Weird. May I ask what version of python are you using so I can test on that version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245272/discussion-between-nguyn-minh-hiu-and-alexpdev).