# Pythonic(OO) way to choose class method depending on the type of object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, polymorphism, single-dispatch

Is there any better **Pythonic** / **Object Oriented** way to choose which particular class method is to be executed at **run time**, depending on the type of the object, since using the `type()` method is not considered *elegant*(?)

I wrote the following code for the three data types I was working with. It basically stores different functions in dictionary as values pairing it with its corresponding object type as keys:

```
import pathlib
import _io

########################################
class choose_for :

    def __init__(self, var):
        func_dict = {str:self.func1, pathlib.WindowsPath:self.func2, _io.TextIOWrapper:self.func3}
        self.func = func_dict[type(var)]

    def func1(self) :
        print("Because it is for STRING like \n")

    def func2(self) :
        print("Because it is for PATH like \n")

    def func3(self) :
        print("Because it is for FILE_POINTER like \n")

    def execute(self):
        print("This object will be executed by : ", self.func)
        self.func()

########################################
var1 = str("something")

var2 = pathlib.Path()

var3 = _io.open("file.txt")

########################################
chosen1 = choose_for(var1)
chosen1.execute()

chosen2 = choose_for(var2)
chosen2.execute()

chosen3 = choose_for(var3)
chosen3.execute()

########################################
var3.close()
```

It gives the following output :

```
This object will be executed by :  <bound method choose_for.func1 of <__main__.choose_for object at 0x0000020A150A3088>>
Because it is for STRING like

This object will be executed by :  <bound method choose_for.func2 of <__main__.choose_for object at 0x0000020A1509EFC8>>
Because it is for PATH like

This object will be executed by :  <bound method choose_for.func3 of <__main__.choose_for object at 0x0000020A15276B48>>
Because it is for FILE_POINTER like
```

Also is there any technical term, for what I am trying to do here?
I think it might be related to single-dispatch, function-overloading or polymorphism, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading)

Comment: See also: [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, indeed, [single-dispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), which Python supports via the `functools` module. No class is needed.

```
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def execute(arg):
    print(f"something with type {type(arg)}")

@execute.register(str):
def _(arg):
    print("Because it is for STRING like \n")

@execute.register(pathlib.Path):
def _(arg):
    print("Because it is for PATH like \n")

@execute.register(io.FileIO)
def _(arg):
    print("Because it is for FILE_POINTER like \n")
```

Testing it, you'll see

```
>>> execute("something")
Because it is for STRING like
>>> execute(pathlib.Path())
Because it is for PATH like
>>> execute(_io.open("file.txt"))
Because it is for FILE_POINTER like
>>> execute(3)
something with type <class 'int'>
```

To use single-dispatch with a method, use `singledispatchmethod`, which will dispatch on the *second* argument of the method, skipping the implicitly provided instance or class argument.