# Why there is no concept of method overloading in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a query on Python language regarding Method Overloading. Just wanted to know why there is no method overloading concept in Python like other Object Oriented languages.

Thank You

Comment: See Why Not Overloading? in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29091980/3890632)

Comment: Method overloading doesn't really make sense in a non statically-typed language. I don't know of any dynamically typed OOP language that supports method overloading. E.g. Ruby.