# Can I require a subset of parameters in a python method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optional-parameters

I have a function that can take either 1 string or 4 strings:

```
def my_function(a, b, c, d, e):
```

I want the user to either pass in `a`, or to pass in `b, c, d and e`. I know that I can make them all default to `None`, but then I need to have logic in my code that ensures that we either get only `a`, or that we get values for all of `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`.

Is there a better way to structure this? I really don't want to have two different methods, but that is also a possibility.

Comment: Having two methods is the proper way to do this. Packing this much logic into a single function makes things very difficult to reason about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading

Comment: What should happen if the user provides values for `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`? It sounds inevitable that you'll need to validate the arguments *at some point*, either inside `my_function` or before calling it. Without looking at the specific needs of your code, I'd say it's better to validate the arguments in another method, and then call `my_function_a` or `my_function_bcde`, depending on the validation resuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're going for.

But this could work:

```
def my_function(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        a = args[0]
        # do stuff with a
    elif len(args) == 4:
        (b, c, d, e) = args
        # do stuff with b,c,d,e
    else:
        raise Exception("Expected 1 or 4 arguments: Got " + str(len(args)))
```

Comment: Note that `if len(args) == 1: a = args[1]` results in an `IndexError`, it should be `args[0]`.