# How to create a class with multiple constructors that take different number of parameters in Python?

Tags: python, parameters, constructor, geometry, arguments

I would like to create a circle class with three parameters (radius, coordinate x and y).

```
class circle:
  def __init__(self, r, x, y): 
    self.radius = r
    self.X = x
    self.Y = y
```

Calling it requires 3 arguments(radius, x and y). Apart from taking 3 arguments like normal, how do I make it to be able to take 1 argument(the radius) and take 2 arguments(coordinate x and coordinate y) at the same time?

For instances, the class can take all of these at the same time:

```
uk = circle(4, 5, 6) #(r, x, y)
uj = circle(1, 2) #(x, y)
uh = circle(8) #(r)
```

Could it be dealt with multiple constructors(overloading, classmethod)?

Comment: Python **does not support method overloading**. Instead, you can 1) Write a signature that could accept any of these and disambiguate the case inside `__init__` 2) use alternative constructors -- probably using `classmethod`.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading) has various useful answers.

Comment: Note you should probably have a single `position` parameter that's a sequence `(x, y)` - those things _belong_ together.