# How do I overload a transform method of a custom class with python?

Tags: python, methods, overriding

I want to make method overloading with Python as below, how can I do it. I want to overload the method that transforms class A.

```
class A:
   value: int
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value=value
variable=A('value:61')
```

Comment: Python does not support function overloading. A name is bound to exactly one thing in Python, and that's the end of the story.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading) help at all?

Comment: from typing import overload

starting in python3.8 I believe it is you can overload.